# Archive files at remover server where file name has "SPACE" and special character

Tags: shell, unix, ssh

I need to archive files with sys time on remote server but name of the file contains "SPACE" and special character. So below commands are not working.

```
FileName="BBB ABC@textfile.xml"
ts=`date +"%m%d%Y%H%M%S"`
 ssh remoteid@remoteserver "'mv /upload/hotfolders/in/"$FileName" 
 /upload/hotfolders/Archive/${FileName}_${ts}'"
```

But above command is failing with below error.
bash: mv /upload/hotfolders/in/BBB ABC@textfile.xml /upload/hotfolders/Archive/BBB ABC@textfile.xml_01282019050200: No 
such file or directory

Comment: I'd be surprised to see that error if you run the exact code shown. Is that the full text of all the error messages? I'd expect several more. The fix for the code as shown is quite trivial (swap the `'` and `"` in the `ssh` line). Explaining why is a bit more longwinded.

Comment: updated the question and error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the original provided code:

```
ssh remoteid@remoteserver 'cd /upload/hotfolders/; mv "$FileName"
    /upload/hotfolders/Archive/"${FileName}_${ts}"'
```

the outermost `'` are used on the local filesystem to keep all the commands as a single argument to ssh. However, this means that `$FileName`, etc are not expanded locally! Instead, the unexpanded strings are passed verbatim to the remoteserver, where a shell is started to run the command. `$FileName`, etc, are then expanded there. Because they are not defined there (probably), the expansion fails to produce anything useful.

In the amended version:

```
 ssh remoteid@remoteserver "'mv /upload/hotfolders/in/"$FileName" 
 /upload/hotfolders/Archive/${FileName}_${ts}'"
```

there is a different problem. Here, the two sets of outermost `"` allow the local system to expand the variables (although it may not be obvious that the first `$FileName` is not actually inside `"`). However, as the command that is passed is now wrapped in `'`, the remote server will treat the entire string as a single word.

If we assume that `FileName` and `ts` will not contain shell-special characters (such as `'`) then the fix is to wrap the command sequence in `"` (so that it expands locally), and only wrap the variables in `'` (so that the remote server treats the now-expanded strings as single words):

```
ssh remoteid@remoteserver "cd /upload/hotfolders/; mv '$FileName'
    /upload/hotfolders/Archive/'${Filename}_${ts}'"
```